# Google Sheets Validation Help Text Not Working

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I'm just making a simple drop-down list in Google sheets and it works fine, but for some reason I cannot get the help text to show. I really need the text because I'd like to have quick explanations of each option. I've tried Googling but all I can find is people with problems with the actual validation part.
[data validation example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcsLa.png)
[data validation example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlZtU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike excel can display both `input message` and `warning message`, Google sheet can only display `warning message` when you enable `reject input` with display message

[image]

The above will only pop up when the user `key in` value different from the list rather than select from the list, your setting is already correct but you cannot expect Google sheet to display message before `reject input`

[image]

However, there is still a way to display message to tell user to only select the list before `reject input`, you can insert `comment` on the cell as following:

[image]

Comment: Gotcha, I was definitely thinking it's like the input message

Comment: Ya, Google not exactly like excel, therefore you need to be creative :)