# Google Sheets customize data validation hover help text

Tags: validation, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, formatting, dropdown

I'm working with a Google Sheet and running into issues with hover text for data validations. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NYwZ_rT0ex-MsV_OIROrQfT_6YWRrBw0C6UssT7WV7A/edit?usp=sharing) is a demo spreadsheet which shows what I am doing.

Essentially, I'm using data validations as a dropdown menu from a range. But, I only want want to show warnings on invalid data. I customized the help text of my warnings, currently set to `This is a custom help text message.` You can see this in the Data > Data Validations menu. However, when you hover over any of the invalid inputs, all you get is `Invalid: Input must fall within specified range`. I want my custom text to show in the red hover section. Is there any way around this? Or is it just a Google Sheets glitch?

[This may be a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68036049/google-sheets-validation-help-text-not-working).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the current state of google sheets data validation settings may sound like misleading, but the functional inquiry of `custom validation help text` is directly bound to the `Reject input` option only:

[image]

where when the unallowed option is forced through the system:

[image]

the custom validation help text is meant to be shown in the message box:

[image]

and not as a hover note assigned to the cell with invalid input:

[image]